How to insert a key if not present to a transparently compared map?
I have a std::map<K, T, std::less<>> and a “key” of type KK which is order-compatible with K. If the key is present, I want to return the corresponding value. If the key is not present, I want to materialize a real key (of type K) and insert a key–value pair with default constructed T into the map.
(My question targets C++14, but borrowing from C++17, you can think of K = std::string and KK = std::string_view, and T = int).
It seems there are two sub-optimal solutions:
This:
auto it = map.insert(std::pair<KK, T>{ key, T{} }).first

Is sub-optimal because it requires materializing a T value even if it’s not needed.
Or:
auto it = map.find(key);
if (it == map.end()) it = map.insert(std::pair<KK, T>{ key, T{} }).first;

Is sub-optimal because of a double lookup.

What is insert? Where is it defined?

Likely meant to be map.insert()

Yes, map.insert. I edited it in.

You can do this with a single lookup by doing the lookup and using one of the insert member functions that take a "hint" iterator:
auto it = map.lower_bound(key);
if (it == map.end() || map.key_comp()(key, it->first)) {
  it = map.emplace_hint(it, std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(key), std::forwrad_as_tuple());
  // Since this will be constructed directly before the hint, lookup isn't done again
}
// `it` points to the existing element or the newly constructed element
// The element is only constructed if it didn't already exist


Transparent maps allow not only keep a key from being materialized, also the second (value) component passed to insert need not be exactly the mapped_type of the map. You can pass any type convertible to the the mapped_type. That way, you can pass a cheap proxy object that creates the value on-demand.
template<typename T>
struct mapped_proxy
{
    operator T() const { return T{}; }
};

auto it = map.insert(std::pair<KK, mapped_proxy<T>>{ key, {} }).first


map[key] does it w/o an extra converting constructor and a proxy object.

@3CxEZiVlQ map[key] is added in C++26

@3CxEZiVlQ template<typename K> std::map::operator[](K&&): The one that doesn't have an extra conversion to the key type for maps with transparent comparators.

@3CxEZiVlQ So in C++14, with a std::string_view key;, map[key] will create a std::string regardless of if it's already in the map, wasting an allocation
